# Running a shell command in IBM cloud through java programme throwing error as java.io.IOException: Cannot run program =13, Permission denied

Tags: java, shell, jmeter, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

My code here, I want to ececute jmeter shell command in IBM cloud through Java.

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec("./JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter -n 
-t ./JMX/"+FileName+" -l ./JTL/Generate_Dashboard.jtl -e -o 
./Result/"+Name+""");
pr.waitFor();
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Well. Permission denied. Have you checked them?

Comment: Is it Cloud Foundry or container on Kubernetes...? Add details on what you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to launch `jmeter.sh` script instead of `jmeter`, it performs environment check, sets up variables, [JVM options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) when it comes to Java 9, etc.
2. You need to ensure that both `jmeter.sh` and `jmeter` have [**execute** permissions](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions), i.e. execute the following command:

   ```
   chmod +x /JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter && chmod +x /JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter.sh
   ```
3. I don't think you need these dots in your command, to wit you need to amend your command to look like:

   ```
   Process pr = run.exec("/JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter -n -t /JMX/"+FileName+" -l /JTL/Generate_Dashboard.jtl -e -o /Result/"+Name+""");
   ```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, I had followed the above steps and issue fixed.